# DatatimePicker C# Select , OR

Tags: c#, .net

In my program as you can see ,there are two `datatimepicker`.
We have two range of data ;
The first for the production date and the second for the statement date.

My objective is to select a range date like `17/07/2019` to `15/04/20`.
But when user is selecting the date with the first option (for example he's selecting the production date) , the second option (for example the statement date) have to be pass in readonly mode.

You have the choice but you can't input two dates.

That i want to say is like

if datatimepicker ( 1 & 2 ) --> datatimepicker 3 & 4 , values.clear + readonly.

I don't know if my question was explicit ..

Please

Br

[The program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a6Qe.png)

Comment: What do you mean: The date should be passed in ReadOnly mode?

Comment: Of by "ReadOnly", you mean you want to restrict the user from clicking the control, you can use the `Enabled` property I guess.

Comment: I can't understand your question at all, but regardless, SO is for help with code and you are not showing any code that you need help with.

Comment: it's like, you can't import the production date AND the statement date, so read-only is like, you can't select the date picker or the date will have to be cleared or changed with a color-box ... To inform the user

Comment: I've all the code for my program but nothing about that cause i don't know where to begin ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like others say it is not easy to understand your question.
But let's say you mean you want to disable the above DatePickers when the below DatePickers values have been set.

Implement the Changed event of the DatePickers and on these events set the properties Enabled to false:

```
private void date1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
date3.Enabled=false;
date4.Enabled = false;
LoadDateFromDB(true);
        }

private void date2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

date3.Enabled=false;
date4.Enabled = false;
    LoadDataFromDB(true);
        }

private void date3_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
date1.Enabled=false;
date2.Enabled = false;
    LoadDataFromDB(false);
        }

private void date4_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

date1.Enabled=false;
date2.Enabled = false;
    LoadDataFromDB(false);
        }

private void LoadDataFromDB(bool firstSet)
{
    if(firstSet)
    {
   // Get Values from DB and use the first date pickers
    }
    else
    {
    // Get values from DB and use the second pair of DatePickers
    }

    // Finally
    ResetDatePickersState();
}

private void ResetDatePickersState()
{
    date1.Enabled=true;
    date2.Enabled = true;
    date3.Enabled=true;
    date4.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: It' exactly that i want to do ! :)

Comment: Ok, but be careful, you will have to find a way to re-enable the DatePickers after they have been disabled. So you should maintain a STATE....

Comment: Change the value if the user using the first and the second datimepicker (Production date range) He can't use the third and the 4th datimepicker too (Statementdate range). So I can use your strategy if for example, when the program can get a value in the first and the second so he will block the third and the 4th

Comment: ho yeah I see what your meaning

Comment: The simplest example of that State maintenance I mean is a button "Enable All", once the user clicks that button, he returns to the original State where all DatePickers are enabled. More advanced solution would be if you manage the State in your code only by "looking" at what the user is doing...It really depends on your logic, how your program works.

Comment: In fact, my program's split in two parts. At the top the search part and the second (basically the list view) it's the database. And the user with this one can search in the database an "FS" and to search her, he can use the datatimepicker but just one and the code will search in the database the date to get back the correct "FS"

Comment: Ok, perfect, so once the DatePicker is changed - go to the DB, return the values you need and reset the DatePickers state. I will modify my answer with that.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try to do that and I will give you a feedback

Comment: Your " First set" means basically "Datatimepicker_1 & Datatimepicker_2"

Comment: Yes, that's right, any code that can tell you that you should use the first 2 date pickers...also you can check if ( DatePicker1.Enabled == true) instead of my FirstSet bool :)

Comment: Basically , if the firstset is selected then the program get values and set them in a variable else the opposite.

Comment: Yes, if you have search button, then use this:
 if ( DatePicker1.Enabled == true) instead of my FirstSet bool

Comment: OOOkk it was so explicit now :') Thank you very much, I started not long ago so I have small difficulties

Answer (score 0):

Simply use value changed event for date time picker ...

like

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker2.Enabled=false;
    dateTimePicker3.Enabled = false;
    dateTimePicker4.Enabled = false;

}

private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dateTimePicker1.Enabled=false;
    dateTimePicker3.Enabled = false;
    dateTimePicker4.Enabled = false;


}
```